# mod_rewrite not working with subdomain

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

So I've spent one too many hours on this- getting a bit desperate.

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^submit/?$ submit.php [NC,L]
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/applicapple:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@perpetualcontrast.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/applicapple
    ServerName applicapple.localhost
    <Directory /var/www/applicapple/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

submit.php definitely exists. **while visiting applicapple.localhost/submit :**

With submit.php in the directory, I get `The requested URL /submit was not found on this server.`

If I remove submit.php, I get `The requested URL /submit.php was not found on this server.`

If I visit localhost/applicapple it works as expected.

Can someone clue me into what is going on here?

Comment: What if you try sub.localhost/submit/ instead of sub.localhost/submit ?

Comment: Same effect, no difference in output ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the MultiViews option in Apache which searches the directory for files with the same name, so /submit gets interpreted as /submit.php if /submit.php exists. I turned off this option and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are ignoring '/'

try this

```
RewriteRule ^/submit/?$ submit.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: sorry- no difference in effect ):

Comment: Could you add  your virtualhost configuration as well as tailed output of access,error and rewrite log?

Answer (score 0):

Your RewritRule is

> RewriteRule ^/submit/?$ submit.php [NC,L]

which i think won't work as it is, because it means 'match /submit to submit.php so if the url is **www.xyz.com/submit** it will be redirected as **www.xyz.*comsubmit.php*** off-course this will result in '400 Bad request' as  your apache server won't know how to handle the request.

I tested  the configuration on my pc that just by editing the rewrite rule  to redirect to /submit.php instead of just submit.php will fix the problem.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/submit/?$ /submit.php
```